# What's the real advantage of using ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptResource?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax

So it eliminates duplicates and does cache-busting (with unique ScriptManager.axd urls). The downside is that everyone is now including their own JS or blocks all over the place and it makes debugging on the client side a pain.

I know this is kind of core to ASP.NET AJAX, but is it really that great or necessary? I prefer having js explicitly included in master pages (for framework level js), or in the ascx control markup directly. Then do things on the client-side with jQuery.

What are the situations where RegisterClientScriptResource (and the other Register...) is required or preferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have self-contained re-usable controls.